# Size problems with the physical device icon when entering the mobile app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, icons

I changed the icon of the physical device and it appears as I want in the mobile apps section but when I enter the app it appears the real shape of the image, what I want is for it to cover the entire white part or white background.
The dimensions are: 512 x 512, width: 512 pixels, height 512 pixels.
the 2 photos that I am placing are of the same image.
The first image is from the home of the apps and the second image is when I enter the app

[image]

[image]